# Power Query - Extract Text after some chactacters only

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to get text after 5 first dashes only, but jus tried some ways still extract text after 6 dashes.

```
if Text.Contains([Column1],"-") and  
       Text.StartsWith([Column1],"- - - - - ")
then Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1],"- - - - - ")
else null
```

Input:

| Raw column |
| --- |
| ----- Kitchen - IL |
| ------ Self-serve |

Output:

| Raw column | Level 1 | Level 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ----- Kitchen - IL | Kitchen - IL | null |
| ------ Self-serve | null | Self-serve |

Comment: How about first replacing 6 consecutive dashes with another character, like Tab?

Comment: @JohnSUN: 
if Text.Contains([Column1],"-") and 
    List.Count(Text.PositionOf([Column1],"-",Occurrence.All)) = 6
else null

Comment: What happens if it turns out that the dash is 7 or more? Perhaps it's better to use `>5` instead of `=6`?

Comment: it worked for 6 dashes when I count 6, but 5 in some cases "-" appears in somewhere, not middle, not in sequence

Comment: @JohnSUN >=6 it will turn for level 6, =5 should be for level 5 ( numbers of dashes in sequence will be no.level

Comment: No, I mean >=6 worked if I split text for level 2 but I need to split text for level 1 after 5 dashes only

Comment: Well, maybe it's easier to add a Level 2 column with the same condition for 6 or more dashes, and only then add Level 1, with the condition `if [Level 2] = null then if "condition for 5 dashes"...`, reorder the columns, and remove the Raw column?

Comment: Thanks, it's good idea. But some cases as "Kitchen - IL" , don't know why it can't extract it.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little snippet:

```
    #"get Level 2" = Table.AddColumn(#"get Raw Column", "Level 2", each if Text.Contains([Raw column],"-") and  
       Text.StartsWith([Raw column],"------") then Text.AfterDelimiter([Raw column],"------") else null),
    #"get Level 1" = Table.AddColumn(#"get Level 2", "Level 1", each if [Level 2] = null then if Text.Contains([Raw column],"-") and  
       Text.StartsWith([Raw column],"-----") then Text.AfterDelimiter([Raw column],"-----") else null else null),
    #"Reorder Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"get Level 1",{"Raw column", "Level 1", "Level 2"})
```

[image: Result Table]

Comment: it still didn't work in case of "Kitchen - IL"

Comment: Sorry the logic is not correct. Level 6 is null or not null, we also split text for level 5 if that row has 5 dashes

Comment: I seem to be confused with the terminology. Did you just mean "Level 6"="Level 2" and "Level 5"="Level 1"?

Comment: Sorry I typed wrong character, thank you so much. It worked finally!